# $L^1(0,T;(L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R^N}))^N)$ - Confused about notations used for space and time dependent vector fields

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, vector-fields

I found this notation - $L^1(0,T;(L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R^N}))^N)$ - in a paper of DiPerna and Lions concerning vector fields space and time dependent, "Ordinary differential equations, transport theory and Sobolev spaces" - Invent. math. 98, 511-547 (1989), and I wasn't able to understand which function they are actually considering.
I tried to search on the net but I wasn't able to find it stated. Supposing this notation to be "standard" in the field could someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $u$ is in this space if
$$\int_0^T\|u(t)\|_{L^1(K;\mathbb R^N)}<\infty,$$
for all $K\subset\mathbb R^N$ that are compact.

Comment: Perfect! What's the notion of weak convergence in this space?

Comment: I don't think there is one since $L^1_{Loc}$ is not a normed space

Comment: Which is exactly why I was confused the authors used that expression, but I guess I now understand what they meant in the passage I'm referring to. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries! I think the closest notion of "weak convergence" you could have for a sequence $u_n$ in this space is by considering the sequence $u_n\varphi$ for some $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ since we now have a sequence in $L^1(0,T;L^1(\mathbb R^N)^N)$ rather than $L^1(0,T;L^1_{\operatorname{Loc}}(\mathbb R^N)^N)$.

Comment: Exactly what I thought!